# SQL subquery scope

Tags: sql, t-sql, scope

```
exists 
    (
    select 1 from dt dt1 inner join pt pt1
    on dt1.map=pt1.map and dt1.pda=pt1.pda
    where c.code=dt1.customer and dt1.canceled=0
    and dt1.doccode in ('02','03') and pt1.exp_value<>0
    and dt1.insdate>='20151001'
    and pt1.item in (
        select item from f_itemset
        where itemset='campaign78' and cat_custom='complexion_sccf')
    )
and not exists
    (
    select 1 from dt dt2 inner join pt pt2
    on dt2.map=pt2.map and dt2.pda=pt2.pda
    where c.code=dt2.customer and dt2.canceled=0
    and dt2.doccode in ('02','03') and pt2.exp_value<>0 
    and dt2.insdate>='20151001'
    and pt2.item not in (
        select item from f_itemset
        where itemset='campaign78' and cat_custom='complexion_sccf')
    )
```

This is in the `where` part of a query, and the tables `pt` and `dt` are also present in the `from` clause.

Are all these aliases (`dt1`, `dt2`, etc) necessary?

Do they become `dt`/`pt`-correlated to the outer query if I do not give them these aliases?

Comment: These two sub-queries are not aware of each other.

Comment: Good, but would they be if the aliases were not there?

Comment: No, table aliases or not make no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this (stupid) query that works perfectly :

```
SELECT * FROM TAGS AS T
WHERE T.[COUNT]< 10
AND T.ID IN (SELECT O.ID FROM TAGS AS O WHERE O.[COUNT]=9 OR O.ID = T.ID)
```

You can see that the subquery uses data from the first one...

Normaly, SQL Server will warn you if it can determine witch table to use, forcing you to set aliases... But remember that you should always put alias.

**So you must keep alias pt1 and pt2 in your query.**

Comment: Wait. Since you called the outer tags T, and you called T inside the subquery, I understand this would happen. The question is: if you neither specified alias T for the outer tags, and alias O for the inner tags, would the subquery correlate the two tags tables, or would it create a subquery-specific scope that would override the outer one, like languages like C do in functions, for example?

Comment: Without any alias : WHERE [COUNT]=9 OR ID = ID SQL Server will consider the seconde ID as the default SELECT table. Meaning 1 = 1...

Comment: ...but the count will be from the subquery's tags?

Comment: Witch count are talking of? My sample (and stupid) query doesn't have one, neither yours...

Comment: I was talking about the O.[COUNT]=9